# Is there a way to get all possible subarrays of length 30 from an array containing numbers 1 to 10000 that multiply to a specific number?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, math, out-of-memory, combinations

I need a way to find all subarrays of length 30 from an array of numbers 1 to 10000 whose contents multiply to a certain value. I have tried using itertools.combinations() but I receive MemoryError much before completion, even if I'm not running anything else. Here is what I've done so far:

```
def WforFactorials(N,k):
    count = 0
    target = math.factorial(N)
    factors = [i for i in range(1,N+1)]
    combs = itertools.combinations(factors ,k)
    for j in range(len(combs)):
    try:
        if int(np.prod(y[j])) == target:
            count+=1
        else:
            del y[j]
    except IndexError:
        pass
print(count)
```

Comment: Do you realise how many combinations there are? Even if it was only an array with 1000 values, it still is [`C(1000 choose 30)`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination) which is circa 6*10^87. That's more than there are atoms in the observable universe. Good look with that -- you'll understand that your PC's memory only has a fraction of those atoms, let be it has anything close in number of bytes.

Comment: @trincot thanks for responding, do you have any suggestions of ways of calculating the number of ways 10000! can be expressed as a product of 30 distinct integers

Comment: It is clear that you shouldn't generate all subarrays. Also, you are not supposed to express 10000!, but `target`. The better approach is to look for all factors of `target` and work with that.

Comment: Your question is poorly explained, and the code you have doesn't match your explanation. I.e., if the target is always N! then that's an important part of the question. Can you update this with the exact problem statement?